# using multiple terms in tax_query

Tags: tax-query

I'm trying to build a real estate search site.

first of all, here is the search form (sorry for german classes and stuff tho):

```
<form  method="post" action="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/immobilien-suche/">
<?php
$taxonomiesImmo = get_object_taxonomies('immobilien');
$termsImmoBundesland = get_terms($taxonomiesImmo[0]);
?>
    <fieldset name="bundeslaender">
        <input type="checkbox" value="alleBundeslaender">alle Bundesl&auml;nder</input>
        <?php foreach ($termsImmoBundesland as $termImmoBundesland) { ?>
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $termImmoBundesland->slug; ?>" name="checkedBundeslaender[]"><?php echo $termImmoBundesland->name; ?></label>
        <?php } ?>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit"/>  
</form>
```

then in my search result page template I implode those multiple checkbox results (array) to get a clean list, like it's stated in the function reference:

```
'terms'    => array( 'action', 'comedy' ), // wordpress codex
```

my implode

```
if ( count($_POST['checkedBundeslaender']) > 1 ) {
    $checkedBundeslaenderList = "'".implode("', '", $_POST['checkedBundeslaender'])."'";
    // string form: 'term1', 'term2', 'term3' ...
} else {
    $checkedBundeslaenderList = $_POST['checkedBundeslaender']);
    // string form: 'term1'
}
```

and finally my query args:

```
$newImmoArgs = array(
    'post_type' => 'immobilien',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'bundesland',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( $checkedBundeslaenderList ),
            'operator' => 'IN',
            'include_children' => false,
        ),
    ),                              

);
```

My problem is, that my query doesn't have any results if there are 2 or more checkboxes checked... its only working when only 1 checkbox is checked.

please help!

best regards, rellston.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up arrays. In your "my implode", `$checkedBundeslaenderList` varies between a string and an array, depending on the number of items.

And then in your query args, you nest it in an array:

```
'terms' => array( $checkedBundeslaenderList ),
```

So what you could end up with is either:

```
array( array( 1 ) );
```

...or:

```
array( '1,2,3,4' );
```

Neither are valid formats. Instead, always use an array:

```
if ( ! empty( $_POST['checkedBundeslaender'] ) ) {
    $checkedBundeslaenderList = wp_unslash( ( array ) $_POST['checkedBundeslaender'] );
} else {
    $checkedBundeslaenderList = array();
}
```

And then just pass it straight to your query:

```
'terms' => $checkedBundeslaenderList,
```

Comment: TheDeadMedic you are my hero! :* works perfectly :) thanks! :D